# Python Tkinter Text/Scrollbar Widget not functioning as expected

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have a homework assignment that I almost have completed, but the scrollbar does not function as expected. While it works when I'm focused on the Text, it does not work when I try to move the scrollbar or use the arrows.

```
from tkinter import *

class LoanCalculator:
    def __init__(self):
        window = Tk()
        window.title("Loan Calculator")

        frame = Frame(window)
        frame.pack()

        Label(frame, text="Loan Amount").grid(row=1,column=1, sticky=W)
        self.loanAmmount = StringVar()
        self.entryLoan = Entry(frame, textvariable=self.loanAmmount, justify=RIGHT)
        Label(frame, text="Years").grid(row=1, column=3,sticky=W)
        self.years = StringVar()
        self.entryYears = Entry(frame, textvariable=self.years, justify=RIGHT)
        btCalc = Button(frame, text="Calculate Loan", command=self.Calculate)
        scrollbar = Scrollbar(frame)
        self.text = Text(frame, width=60, height=10,wrap=WORD, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

        self.entryLoan.grid(row=1, column=2)
        self.entryYears.grid(row=1, column=4)
        btCalc.grid(row=1, column=5)
        self.text.grid(row=2,column=1,columnspan=4)
        scrollbar.grid(row=2, column=5, sticky="NSW")



        window.mainloop()

    def Calculate(self):
        self.text.delete("1.0", END)
        self.text.insert(END, "{0:<20s}{1:<20s}{2:<20s}".format("Interest Rate", "Monthly Payment", "Total Payment"))
        aIR = 5.0
        mIR = 0
        mP = 0
        tP = 0
        fLA = 0
        fYear = 0
        lA = 0
        year = 0
        textToOut = ""
        while aIR <= 8.0:
            fLA = self.loanAmmount.get()
            fYear = self.years.get()
            lA = int(fLA)
            year = int(fYear)
            mIR = aIR / 1200
            mP = lA * mIR / (1 - (pow(1 / (1 + mIR), year * 12)))
            tP = mP * year * 12
            textToOut = format(aIR, ">5.3f") + "%" + format(mP, "20.2f") + format(tP, "20.2f") + "\n"
            self.text.insert(END, textToOut)
            aIR += 1.0 / 8


LoanCalculator()
```

**EDIT**
I've changed my question to drop the text portion, as I have figured a workaround for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure the scrollbar to run an action (update the view of the text area) on scrolling. Add this line of code after you defined your text area.

```
scrollbar.config(command=self.text.yview)
```

So the code block of `__init__` would be something like this:

```
def __init__(self):
    window = Tk()
    window.title("Loan Calculator")

    frame = Frame(window)
    frame.pack()

    Label(frame, text="Loan Amount").grid(row=1,column=1, sticky=W)
    self.loanAmmount = StringVar()
    self.entryLoan = Entry(frame, textvariable=self.loanAmmount, justify=RIGHT)
    Label(frame, text="Years").grid(row=1, column=3,sticky=W)
    self.years = StringVar()
    self.entryYears = Entry(frame, textvariable=self.years, justify=RIGHT)
    btCalc = Button(frame, text="Calculate Loan", command=self.Calculate)
    scrollbar = Scrollbar(frame)
    self.text = Text(frame, width=60, height=10,wrap=WORD, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
    scrollbar.config(command=self.text.yview)

    self.entryLoan.grid(row=1, column=2)
    self.entryYears.grid(row=1, column=4)
    btCalc.grid(row=1, column=5)
    self.text.grid(row=2,column=1,columnspan=4)
    scrollbar.grid(row=2, column=5, sticky="NSW")
```